# Using loopback with Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, azure-cosmosdb, loopbackjs

Is it possible to use Loopback 3.x with azure Cosmos DB (assuming I don't want to create my own connector)? I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-connector-cosmosdb which isn't officially supported and I couldn't get it work. I have been looking for a quick way to set up an API on Azure (honestly I prefer SQL over CosmosDB but it seems like the simpler way to go) using NodeJS and haven't come across one yet. I started coding serverless functions for my API which work wonderfully except that adding authentication seems like a total drag and goes over my head completely. I indent to create both a web app and iOS App for what I'm developing any suggestions would be great!